# Type 'UIGestureRecognizer' has no member 'State'

Tags: ios

I get the following error in the `LongPressViewController` class.

```
import UIKit

class LongPressViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func btnTekan(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
            let  alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Long Press terdeteksi", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

            self.present(alertController, animated: true)

        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(_:)))

    }
    @objc func handleLongPress(_ recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05,
                           animations: {
                            self.imgView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
            },
                           completion: nil)
        case .ended:
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05) {
                self.imgView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: in which line u faced this issue

Comment: tried your code everything works, try to clean your project

Comment: Type `UIGestureRecognizer` has the member `State`. Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/state

Answer (score 1):

### Warning: your code is incomplete

You should indicate *what* error is reported on *which line* of your code.

As is, your code may warn you that the constant `longPressGesture` declared and initialized in `viewDidLoad()` was never used. This is not an error, but just a friendly reminder that this line has no effect. You may attach the recognizer to the controlled view by adding the following line:

```
view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
```

Alternatively, you can declare `longPressGesture` as an `@IBOutlet` and attach it in Interface Builder.

Further up where you use `State`, the property `state` implies already the type `UIGestureRecognizer.State`, so you may shorten your line to

```
if sender.state == .began {
```